# Como insiro um valor em todos os registro de uma coluna de uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Tenho a tabela 'categoria' e uma coluna 'id', sendo que nessa coluna tem mais de 100 registros.

Como faço para adicionar um valor a todos esses registro? No caso o valor seria '3'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma instrução do tipo *UPDATE* - quando se tem registros na tabela e quer atualizá-los - é feita da seguinte maneira através do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE nome_tabela SET campo = valor
```

- A instrução *UPDATE* atualiza colunas de linhas existentes na tabela com nomes com novos valores.
- A cláusula *SET* indica quais colunas modificar e os valores que devem ser fornecidos.

No seu caso, para **atualizar o valor de todos registros** você simplesmente retira a cláusula *WHERE* - usada para filtrar/restringir alguns registros - e então basta fazer uma *query* semelhante a essa:

```
UPDATE categoria SET campo = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que o campo que você quer atualizar se chama `campo`:

```
UPDATE categoria
SET campo = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update categoria set coluna='3' where coluna != '3'
```

Imagino que seja algo assim.
Isso só funciona no console ou se vc desativar segurança do mysql, pois ele nao deixa por segurança

Answer (score 2):

**Instrução MySQL:**

```
UPDATE Categoria
SET Campo = 3
```

Isso faz com que todos os valores da coluna "Campo" sejam alterados para "3".
Se existe a necessidade de fazer isso para linhas específicas, necessário a utilização de um condicional (`WHERE`).

Abraço.